# Why am I getting "invalid_grant: Invalid JWT Signature" with Google's Python TTS example?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client, google-text-to-speech

I've followed the instructions for using Google's Python client for text-to-speech. The [example](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) freezes at the actual request line. Hitting control-C produces a trace ending with "invalid_grant: Invalid JWT Signature". I've verified that my key is active, the time on my machine is correct (for my location), and that "gcloud auth login" works properly. I've tried making a new key but encounter the same issue. How do I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Delete the service account "key" in the console. Issue a new key and download the JSON file. Specify that file for `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. If you still have a problem, post your code, OS version, Python version, versions of imports, environment variables, and the exact error message.

Comment: I can see your deleted answer. Post a new answer with the solution. If I understand correctly, the environment variable `GOOGLE-APPLICATION-CREDENTIALS` was pointing to the wrong credentials file. Include more details on how you were running the code as you mentioned Windows Settings Admin. You might have been developing with one account and running the code with another (system) account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For context, I'm using Windows 10 and Python 3.7.9. I deleted the key and created a new one exactly as John Hanley suggested. But, the problem continued when I ran my code in both my IDE (Visual Studio Code) and a separate Windows Command Prompt, which I was also using to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. I decided to check the environment variable directly in Windows Settings with admin privileges. I saw that GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS was still set to an old JSON credentials file -- it had not changed. My only explanation is that I must not have opened the command prompt with admin privileges. I then set the environment variable to the new JSON file directly in Windows Settings. Google's Python client example for text-to-speech then ran correctly.